# how to add container node in json string at runtime in java

Tags: java, json, string

I have below json input String containing node TestInfo

```
{

            "TestInfo" : [ {
            }
            ]

}
```

I want to add container node to the TestInfo like below

```
{
     "TestInfoContainer":{
            "TestInfo" : [ {
            }
            ]
      }

}
```

Kindly suggest me way to do this with good performance as this could be applicable to actual big hierarchical structure

1. Is it easy with any JSON parser
2. Is it easy with string manipulation

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have not tried it any way yet

Comment: You can do this with JSON parser

Answer (score 0):

With JSON parser its easy

```
JSONObject node = new JSONObject(nodeJsonString);
JSONObject container = new JSONObject(containerJsonString);

container.put("TestInfoContainer", node.getJSONArray("TestInfo"));
```

(EDIT) Given nested JSON object

```
{"TestInfo":[{}],"A":{"B":{"C":{"TestInfo":[{}]}}},"D":{"TestInfo":[{}]},"E":{"F":{"G":{"H":{"TestInfo":[{}]}}}}}
```

You get value down hierarchy by calling methods in chain

```
container.getJSONObject("TestInfoContainer").put("TestInfo1",jObject.getJSONArray("TestInfo"));

    container.getJSONObject("TestInfoContainer").put("TestInfo2",jObject.getJSONObject("A")
                                                                        .getJSONObject("B")
                                                                        .getJSONObject("C")
                                                                        .getJSONArray("TestInfo"));

    container.getJSONObject("TestInfoContainer").put("TestInfo3",jObject.getJSONObject("D")
                                                                        .getJSONArray("TestInfo"));

    container.getJSONObject("TestInfoContainer").put("TestInfo4",jObject.getJSONObject("E")
                                                                        .getJSONObject("F")
                                                                        .getJSONObject("G")
                                                                        .getJSONObject("H")
                                                                        .getJSONArray("TestInfo"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but what if I have multiple nodes and hierarchical json structure like

{
    
            "TestInfo" : [ {  }   ],
       "A":{ 
"B":{
"C":{
 "TestInfo" : [ {  }   ]
}
}
},
"D":{
 "TestInfo" : [ {  }   ]
},
"E":{
"F":{
"G":{
"H":{
 "TestInfo" : [ {  }   ],
}
}
}
}

}